# html e-mail sent from Outlook text-align left doesn't work in gmail IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, outlook, gmail, html-email

I know this question is asked before and I think I almost tried everything that others have suggested. But here is my problem:

I **have** to send the html e-mail with Outlook (not in a browser, part of the office suite), that's not a choice. I use tables, in tables etc. To center the e-mail I use a `table align="center"`, have tried to put it on the td too, no different result. Whatever I do, when I try to put `text-align=left;` on anything inside that table, it centers the text in Gmail and Outlook when viewed in IE.... In Firefox and Chrome it looks normal with my text aligned left, but only in IE it does this. Problem is, the people we are going to send it to only work with IE and Outlook, and Gmail....

I've tried for days now, nothing works, I have tried dozens of tips from others, nothing works.

Just as simple as next example doesn't work:

```
<table width="600" align="center">
   <tr>
      <td align="left" style="text-align:left;">Some text</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Even templates from tutorials that I've read give the same damn mistakes.
Anyone knows how to fix this problem or am I doomed because this e-mail has to be sent from Outlook and his Word rendering engine.....and has to be viewed in IE.... by gmail as well.....

---

I tried the exact code that was given to me by the generous Gortonington:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Testing</title>
<style type="text/css"> 
/**This is to overwrite Outlook.com’s Embedded CSS************/ 
table {border-collapse:separate;} 
a, a:link, a:visited {text-decoration: none; color: #00788a} 
a:hover {text-decoration: underline;} 
h2,h2 a,h2 a:visited,h3,h3 a,h3 a:visited,h4,h5,h6,.t_cht {color:#000 !important} 
.ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td {line-height: 100%} /**This is to center your email in Outlook.com************/ 
.ExternalClass {width: 100%;} 
  </style>
</head>
<body style="margin:0; padding:0;background-color:#CCCCCC;">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <tr>
          <td align="left">
            Your text here... Lalalalalal Lalalalala Lalalalala
            <br/>
            lalalalalalalalala
            <br/>
            lalalalala
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I mailed it with Outlook (Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010)--> that's what we work with

And the result in Gmail and old Hotmail/new Outlook in browser IE (10) is still a centered text. I would like to post pictures, but I don't have enough reputation for that...

**UPDATE:**
As requested, the code **Outlook.com** in IE makes of the e-mail:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML Strict//EN"><META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<html class="m_ul fh  hnl  useCss3" xml:lang="nl" lang="nl" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><style>
*
{
    line-height: 142%;
}
body
{
    color: #000;
    font-family: "Segoe UI","Segoe UI Web Regular","Segoe UI Symbol","Helvetica Neue","BBAlpha Sans","S60 Sans",Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 88%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    direction: ltr;
    background-image: none;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position-x: left;
    background-position-y: top;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
p
{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 1.35em;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
html.fh
{
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
html.fh .c_base
{
    left: 0px;
    top: 40px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: auto;
    min-width: 964px;
}
html.hnl.fh .c_base
{
    top: 50px;
}
div.c_main
{
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
::selection
{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgb(0, 114, 198);
}
.t_mbgc, #c_h_theme_m
{
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.t_qtc, .t_qtc:hover, .t_qtc:visited, .mlRd .t_estc
{
    color: #444;
}
body
{
    display: none;
}
body
{
    display: block !important;
}
body
{
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.DefaultFont, body, textarea, select, input
{
    color: #000;
}
body
{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
body
{
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    border-top-color: currentColor !important;
    border-right-color: currentColor !important;
    border-bottom-color: currentColor !important;
    border-left-color: currentColor !important;
    border-top-width: 0px !important;
    border-right-width: 0px !important;
    border-bottom-width: 0px !important;
    border-left-width: 0px !important;
    border-top-style: none !important;
    border-right-style: none !important;
    border-bottom-style: none !important;
    border-left-style: none !important;
    position: static !important;
}
body.IE_M10
{
    -ms-touch-action: pinch-zoom;
}
.ClearBoth
{
    clear: both;
}
html.fh .c_base
{
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: visible;
    min-width: 0px;
}
#pageInbox
{
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    -ms-touch-action: none;
}
.AppContainer
{
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
.v-ReadMessageContainer
{
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    outline-width: medium;
    outline-style: none;
    outline-color: invert;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
}
.FullView .v-ReadMessageContainer
{
    left: 0px !important;
    top: 0px !important;
    right: 0px !important;
}
.ContentRight
{
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 588px;
}
.ContentRightInner
{
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
.FullView .ContentRightInner
{
    bottom: 2.2em;
}
.WithRightRail
{
    right: 160px;
    min-width: 428px;
}
#ReadMessageScrollableSection
{
    outline-width: medium;
    outline-style: none;
    outline-color: invert;
}
.c-ReadMessage
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
    outline-width: medium;
    outline-style: none;
    outline-color: invert;
}
.c-ReadMessage .rmMessages
{
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.c-ReadMessagePart
{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-top-color: #ccc;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    position: relative;
}
.c-ReadMessagePartBody .readMsgBody
{
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -ms-touch-select: grippers;
}
.containsYSizerBar
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.Snippet, .ExternalClass
{
    font-family: Calibri,sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.slideOnResize
{
    transition-property: top, left, right;
    transition-duration: 367ms, 367ms, 367ms;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.9, 0.2, 1), cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.9, 0.2, 1), cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.9, 0.2, 1);
    transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0s;
}
body
{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.ExternalClass p.ecxMsoNormal, .ExternalClass li.ecxMsoNormal, .ExternalClass div.ecxMsoNormal
{
    font-family: "Calibri","sans-serif";
    font-size: 11pt;
}

</style></head>
<body class="t_body ltr SignedIn IE IE_Win Win6 IE_M10 IE_D0 Full RE_Trident NoTouch" id="&#47;ol&#47;mail.fpp" style="cursor: auto;"><div class="AppContainer"><div class="c_base" id="c_base" style="top: 50px;"><div class="c_main" id="c_content"><div id="pageContent"><div class="v-Page" id="pageInbox"><div id="inboxControl0f"><div class="containsYSizerBar"><div class="ContentRight WithRightRail FullView" style="left: 205px;" data-link="class{:~tag.contentRightClass(Layout.IsFullView, Layout.ReadingPaneMode)}"><div class="ContentRightInner t_mbgc t_qtc t_urtc"><div tabindex="-1" class="v-ReadMessageContainer slideOnResize" id="inboxControl0fv-ReadMessageContainer" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: null; animation-duration: 0s; animation-timing-function: ease; animation-delay: 0s; animation-direction: normal; animation-iteration-count: 1; animation-fill-mode: none;"><div class="c-ReadMessage" data-link="class{readMessageClass: ~tag.Show}"><div tabindex="-1" class="rmMessages ClearBoth" id="ReadMessageScrollableSection"><div class="c-ReadMessagePart ReadMsgContainer HasLayout ClearBoth HideShadows FullPart NoHistory Read RmIc" id="readMessagePartControl398f" data-link="class{:~tag.getHeaderCssClass(IsConversationPart, IsRead, IsDraft, IsTrustedSender, Items.length)}"><div class="c-ReadMessagePartBody" data-link="class{getClass:IsBodyExpanded}">

<div class="readMsgBody">

 <div class="ExternalClass MsgBodyContainer" id="bodyreadMessagePartBodyControl403f" data-link="class{:~tag.cssClasses(PlainText, IsContentFiltered)}">
  <style>
   .ExternalClass p.ecxMsoNormal {
    font-family: "Calibri","sans-serif";
    font-size: 11pt;
   }
   .ExternalClass li.ecxMsoNormal {
    font-family: "Calibri","sans-serif";
    font-size: 11pt;
   }
   .ExternalClass div.ecxMsoNormal {
    font-family: "Calibri","sans-serif";
    font-size: 11pt;
   }
   .ExternalClass a:link {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
   }
   .ExternalClass span.ecxMsoHyperlink {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
   }
   .ExternalClass span.ecxMsoHyperlinkFollowed {
    color: purple;
    text-decoration: underline;
   }
   .ExternalClass p.ecxMsoAcetate {
    font-family: "Tahoma","sans-serif";
    font-size: 8pt;
   }
   .ExternalClass li.ecxMsoAcetate {
    font-family: "Tahoma","sans-serif";
    font-size: 8pt;
   }
   .ExternalClass div.ecxMsoAcetate {
    font-family: "Tahoma","sans-serif";
    font-size: 8pt;
   }
   .ExternalClass span.ecxE-mailStijl17 {
    color: windowtext;
    font-family: "Calibri","sans-serif";
   }
   .ExternalClass span.ecxBallontekstChar {
    font-family: "Tahoma","sans-serif";
   }
   .ExternalClass .ecxMsoChpDefault {
    font-family: "Calibri","sans-serif";
   }
   .ExternalClass div.ecxWordSection1 {

   }
  </style>
  <div class="ecxWordSection1">
   <table width="100%" class="ecxMsoNormalTable" style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td style="padding-top: 0cm; padding-right: 0cm; padding-bottom: 0cm; padding-left: 0cm;">
       <div align="center">
        <table width="600" class="ecxMsoNormalTable" style="width: 450pt; background-image: none; background-attachment: scroll; background-repeat: repeat; background-position-x: 0%; background-position-y: 0%; background-size: auto; background-origin: padding-box; background-clip: border-box; background-color: white;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
         <tbody>
          <tr>
           <td style="padding-top: 0cm; padding-right: 0cm; padding-bottom: 0cm; padding-left: 0cm;">
            <p class="ecxMsoNormal">
             Your text here... Lalalalalal Lalalalala Lalalalala <br />lalalalalalalalala <br />lalalalala <span style="font-size: 12pt;"></span>
            </p>
           </td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
       </div>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   <p class="ecxMsoNormal">
    &nbsp;
   </p>
   <p class="ecxMsoNormal">
    &nbsp;
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>

</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></body></html>
```

What **Gmail** in IE makes of it:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML Strict//EN"><META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<html class="aAX">
<head><style>
body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
body, td, input, textarea, select
{
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
}
html
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
html.aAX
{
    overflow: visible;
}
.aAU
{
    overflow-x: visible;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
body, td, input, textarea, select
{
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.nH
{
    zoom: 1;
}
.no
{
    float: left;
}
.nn
{
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
}
.Bs
{
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    position: relative;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.Bu
{
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.aeJ
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-image: none;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position-x: 0%;
    background-position-y: 0%;
    background-size: auto;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color: white;
}
.aeF
{
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.ads
{
    border-left-color: transparent;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-left-style: solid;
}
.Bk
{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.Bk .G2
{
    padding-top: 3px;
    border-top-color: #cfcfcf;
    border-right-color: #cfcfcf;
    border-bottom-color: #cfcfcf;
    border-left-color: #cfcfcf;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.Bk
{
    border-top-color: #efefef;
    border-right-color: #efefef;
    border-bottom-color: #e2e2e2;
    border-left-color: #efefef;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
}
.aAT, .aAU
{
    background-image: none;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position-x: 0%;
    background-position-y: 0%;
    background-size: auto;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.MsoNormal
{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.hx
{
    background-color: transparent;
}
.hx .Bk
{
    float: none;
}
.hx .adn, .hx .adu, .hx .adf
{
    padding-left: 8px;
}
.hx .gs
{
    margin-left: 44px;
}
.hx .ky .Bk .G2, .hx .kv .Bk .G2, .hx .h7 .Bk .G2
{
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    border-top-color: #d8d8d8;
    border-right-color: currentColor;
    border-bottom-color: #d8d8d8;
    border-left-color: currentColor;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}
.hx .h7 .Bk .G2 .adn
{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.hx .h7 .Bk, .hx .kv .Bk, .hx .ky .Bk
{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.hx .ky .Bk, .hx .kv .Bk, .hx .h7 .Bk, .hx .kQ .Bk
{
    border-right-color: currentColor;
    border-bottom-color: currentColor;
    border-left-color: currentColor;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}
.hx .ii
{
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.adn
{
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.hx
{
    color: #222;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-left: 8px;
}
.h7
{
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    max-width: 100000px;
}
.iY
{
    width: 100%;
    background-image: none;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position-x: 0%;
    background-position-y: 0%;
    background-size: auto;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.if
{
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.gt
{
    font-size: 80%;
}
.ii
{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    position: relative;
    direction: ltr;
}
.g
{
    color: #222;
}
.AO
{
    position: relative;
}
.iY
{
    position: static !important;
}
.hx
{
    padding-left: 4px;
}
.aHU
{
    position: relative;
}
.if
{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.aBU, .hx .ky, .hx .kv, .hx .h7, .hx .kQ, .adx
{
    outline-width: medium;
    outline-style: none;
    outline-color: invert;
}
.MsoNormal
{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.hx
{
    min-width: 502px;
}
html.aAX
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
body.aAU
{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
.aeJ, .age
{
    padding-right: 15px;
}
.hx
{
    padding-left: 0px;
}
div.m14daf49cca364ccb p.MsoNormal, div.m14daf49cca364ccb li.MsoNormal, div.m14daf49cca364ccb div.MsoNormal
{
    font-family: "Calibri","sans-serif";
    font-size: 11pt;
    margin-top: 0cm;
    margin-right: 0cm;
    margin-bottom: 0pt;
    margin-left: 0cm;
}

</style></head>
<body class="aAU"><div style="position: relative; min-height: 100%;"><div class="nH" style="width: 1280px;"><div class="nH" style="position: relative;"><div class="nH"><div class="no"><div class="nH nn" style="width: 1075px;"><div class="nH"><div class="nH"><div class="ar4 z"><div class="AO"><div class="Tm aeJ" id=":4" style="height: 805px;" unselectable="on"><div class="aeF" id=":2" style="min-height: 377px;"><div class="nH"><div class="nH" role="main"><div class="nH g id"><table class="Bs nH iY" role="presentation" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><td class="Bu"><div class="nH if"><div class="nH aHU"><div class="nH hx"><div class="nH"><div tabindex="-1" class="h7 ie nH oy8Mbf"><div class="Bk"><div class="G3 G2"><div><div id=":p8"><div class="adn ads"><div class="gs"><div class="ii gt m14daf49cca364ccb adP adO" id=":pa"><div class="a3s" id=":p9" style="overflow: hidden;"><div lang="NL-BE" vlink="purple" link="blue"><div><table width="100%" style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><td style="padding-top: 0cm; padding-right: 0cm; padding-bottom: 0cm; padding-left: 0cm;">

<div align="center">
 <table width="600" style="width: 450pt; background-image: none; background-attachment: scroll; background-repeat: repeat; background-position-x: 0%; background-position-y: 0%; background-size: auto; background-origin: padding-box; background-clip: border-box; background-color: white;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td style="padding-top: 0cm; padding-right: 0cm; padding-bottom: 0cm; padding-left: 0cm;">
     <p class="MsoNormal">
      Your text here... Lalalalalal Lalalalala Lalalalala <br />lalalalalalalalala <br />lalalalala <span style="font-size: 12pt;"><u></u><u></u></span>
     </p>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>

</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></body></html>
```

Comment: I have tried the above code sent from Outlook 07-13 and views on OWA and Gmail in all versions above 8 of IE and could not replicate the issue...have you tried with just the base code above or have you added other code inside? If added code it may be that coding that is causing the issue. I would need to see it in order to find the issue.

Comment: This is the exact example I used. I thought it would be best to start with something like this and then go from there. But that means you can' t replicate the problem. Could it be settings of the Outlook I'm using? Are you sending it from a Mac or a windows computer?

Comment: how do you insert the HTML into Outlook? Do you do the Insert > Insert as Text approach?

Comment: Yes, correct. That didn't work so I have also tried to email it straight from IE, through file>email page (not the exact terms, but you know what I mean) So now I'm running out of options. Pulled my hair out several times....

Comment: O yeah, I have also tried to open the email in IE and Copy everything straight into Outlook. Didn't work either...

Comment: can you do me a favor and post the source of the email that is received in the IE of Outlook.com or Gmail? I am running out of ideas on what this could be. Maybe seeing the end code that Microsoft sends out I can find what is going on.

Comment: I'm currently on a vacation and I already deleted the testing e-mails. (And the Windows laptop that I'm using for work is not with me) As soon as I get back I'll post it here. Thanks again for your time. :)

Comment: Damn, I totally forgot about this. I'm so sorry. But if you're still willing to help out. What exactly do you need  Gortonington? The whole page or just the piece of the e-mail?

Comment: Prefer the full source code from the email received (view source) in outlook. It sounds like it is an issue when rewritten by MSWordHTML and seeing that may help find solution.

Comment: two things to try (Outlook and/or gmail strips the 'align="left"' from the td, no idea how...) 1.) add style="text-align:left;" to the td and 2.) add a p tag with text align left around the text - <p style="text-align:left; margin:0 padding:0">. I do not have my Outlook here to test it, but seems to work and in theory should be retained...

Comment: I'll try it out as soon as I can. To be continued...

Answer (score 2):

I have the same exact problem, and i know how, dont know why, but put it in the head tag fix the problem
NOTE: You have to put your text in P tag

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <style type="text/css">
     p {
          text-align: justify
     }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a 100% table with align left inside the td of the align center table and put the text in that.

The code gets changed from Outlook into a travesty that makes it so gmail does not read td styling correctly. It instead makes it inherit by default - causing the align center. By creating a new nested table, you should be able to regain control of alignment.

Found a similar question that may have a fix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221221/html-emails-center-aligning-tables-affects-cell-text-in-internet-explorer).  Try wrapping it in a 100% container table and then on the TD tag before your 600px table, set that to align="center".  This should center the table without setting the inherit value to center.

E.G.

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td align="left">
            Your text here...
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry for the delay, but I was very busy. I tried it, but it keep text align as center...

Comment: try adding table-layout:fixed and margin:0 auto on the container table

Comment: Thanks Gortonington for your time. I tried it, but IE keeps centering the text...

Comment: I had edited my answer above with another solution - did you check that or just my comment above.  The solution I added in my answer worked for me in all versions of IE across all email clients.

Comment: Might also want to make sure you have the following resets in your header:

<style type="text/css">
/**This is to overwrite Outlook.com’s Embedded CSS************/
table {border-collapse:separate;}
a, a:link, a:visited {text-decoration: none; color: #00788a} 
a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
h2,h2 a,h2 a:visited,h3,h3 a,h3 a:visited,h4,h5,h6,.t_cht {color:#000 !important}
.ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td {line-height: 100%}
/**This is to center your email in Outlook.com************/
.ExternalClass {width: 100%;}
</style>

Comment: Thanks, I will try it immediately! I'll let you know. i think I had a few of them in my header, but not all. I'll let you know!

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem, and replies from outlook to customers were a must-have.
My solution was not using align/ text-align center at all.
Instead, I added two columns to the wrapping table, each with width="50%".
This solved the problem, and worked in all major clients (tested with emailonacid).

My code (also includes some other quirks):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>Security Report</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
 <style type="text/css">
    .ReadMsgBody {
  width: 100%;
 }

 .ExternalClass {
  width: 100%;
 }

 span.yshortcuts {
  color: #000;
  background-color: none;
  border: none;
 }

 span.yshortcuts:hover, span.yshortcuts:active, span.yshortcuts:focus {
  color: #000;
  background-color: none;
  border: none;
 }

 a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
  color: inherit !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  font-size: inherit !important;
  font-family: inherit !important;
  font-weight: inherit !important;
  line-height: inherit !important;
 }</style>
</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="table-layout:fixed;border-collapse:collapse;">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
  <td width="50%" colspan="1" rowspan="1"></td>
  <td bgcolor="#FBFBFB" width="600" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" width="600"
          style="table-layout:fixed;border-collapse:collapse;border:solid 1px #E9E9E9;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td width="100%" align="left" style="border: 1px solid rgb(233, 233, 233);" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
     </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </td>
  <td width="50%" colspan="1" rowspan="1"></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<style type="text/css">.ReadMsgBody {
 width: 100%;
}

.ExternalClass {
 width: 100%;
}

span.yshortcuts {
 color: #000;
 background-color: none;
 border: none;
}

span.yshortcuts:hover, span.yshortcuts:active, span.yshortcuts:focus {
 color: #000;
 background-color: none;
 border: none;
}

a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
 color: inherit !important;
 text-decoration: none !important;
 font-size: inherit !important;
 font-family: inherit !important;
 font-weight: inherit !important;
 line-height: inherit !important;
}</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

**Update** This solution causes Gmail and Yahoo to show the content right-aligned, so don't use it. I'm looking for other solutions which does not require the align attribute/css...

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out as soon as possible!